# Change the initial time plotted in a time series - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset composed of hourly temperature samples. The sampling starts at 16:00 and I would like to label the x-axis every 6 hours starting at 16:00. In my attempts I manage to do the following:

[image]

The thing i couldn't figure out is why the plot is starting at 16:07.
Is there a way to set the first time plotted to be 16:00?

My plot:

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales)
grafico <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x = dt, y = temp))
grafico <- grafico + geom_line(size=0.3, color="red3")
grafico <- grafico + scale_x_datetime( breaks = date_breaks("6 hour"), labels = date_format("%H:%m"), minor_breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"), expand = c(0, 0))
grafico <- grafico + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

my data:

```
dt  temp
2014-07-24 16:00:00 10.467
2014-07-24 17:00:00 10.638
2014-07-24 18:00:00 7.720
2014-07-24 19:00:00 2.797
2014-07-24 20:00:00 1.886
2014-07-24 21:00:00 0.412
2014-07-24 22:00:00 0.246
2014-07-24 23:00:00 0.632
2014-07-25 00:00:00 -0.676
2014-07-25 01:00:00 -0.676
2014-07-25 02:00:00 -1.384
2014-07-25 03:00:00 -1.213
2014-07-25 04:00:00 -3.124
2014-07-25 05:00:00 -1.327
2014-07-25 06:00:00 -1.929
2014-07-25 07:00:00 -1.157
2014-07-25 08:00:00 -1.242
2014-07-25 09:00:00 2.850

structure(list(dt = structure(1:18, .Label = c("2014-07-24 16:00:00", 
"2014-07-24 17:00:00", "2014-07-24 18:00:00", "2014-07-24 19:00:00", 
"2014-07-24 20:00:00", "2014-07-24 21:00:00", "2014-07-24 22:00:00", 
"2014-07-24 23:00:00", "2014-07-25 00:00:00", "2014-07-25 01:00:00", 
"2014-07-25 02:00:00", "2014-07-25 03:00:00", "2014-07-25 04:00:00", 
"2014-07-25 05:00:00", "2014-07-25 06:00:00", "2014-07-25 07:00:00", 
"2014-07-25 08:00:00", "2014-07-25 09:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
temp = c(10.467, 10.638, 7.72, 2.797, 1.886, 0.412, 0.246, 
0.632, -0.676, -0.676, -1.384, -1.213, -3.124, -1.327, -1.929, 
-1.157, -1.242, 2.85)), .Names = c("dt", "temp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I'm very new to R.
Any advice in the code is welcomed.

Comment: Are you using the current version of ggplot2? I'm not finding a function by the name of `data_breaks`.  _Furhermore_, there is no column named "Temp" in your data. And when I load pkg:scales and fix the misspelling I get an error. SO .... post `dput(asdas)` instead of a console output that requires `read.zoo` or some other unspecified processing.

Comment: I checked and I'm running R 3.1.0 and ggplot2 0.9.3.1. Also, I edited my post and added the dput(). I didn't know about this function that's why I posted the console output.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are using `%H:%m` as your date format.  Lowercase `m` means month here (hence the `07` - all of your dates are in July).  You need an uppercase M for minutes - `%H:%M`. See the help page for `strptime` for more details.

Comment: @aosmith Good catch. It also highlights the value of formatting your SO code so that it fits into the viewing window. I suspect it would have been seen earlier had this been done.